# How to show single table row date in multiple page in dompdF laravel 9

Tags: pdf-generation, dompdf, laravel-dompdf

I want to show a long data set in a single table in PDF generation using dompdf in Laravel. my problem is if the content how much the page size still shows on the first page only. that means the table, not the reader to the second page.can show single table row in multiple page?

```
<table style="width:100%;" border="1" id="details">
        <tr style="font-size: 14px;text-align:center;">
            <td width="5%">
                <p style="text-align: center;"><b>SN</b></p>
            </td>
            <td width="15%">
                <p style="padding-left: 10px"><b>Name,Address & Date of Birth</b></p>
            </td>
            <td width="25%">
                <p style="padding-left: 10px"><b>Education Qulification</b></p>
            </td>
            <td width="25%">
                <p style="padding-left: 10px"><b>Professional Qulifications/Research & Publications<b></p>
            </td>
            <td width="30%">
                <p style="padding-left: 10px"><b>Pervious Position Held with Date</b></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr style="font-size: 12px;">
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                <p style="text-align: center;">{{ sprintf("%02d", $sn) }}</p>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                <p style="padding-left: 10px">
                    {{ $appData->applicantTitle->category_name }} {{ ucfirst($appData->initials) }}  {{ ucfirst($appData->last_name) }}<br>
                    {{ ucfirst($appData->permanent_add1) }},<br> @if($appData->permanent_add2 != '') {{ ucfirst($appData->permanent_add2) }}, @endif <br>@if($appData->permanent_add3 != '') {{ ucfirst($appData->permanent_add3) }}, @endif <br>{{ ucfirst($appData->pCity->name_en) }}.<br><br>
                    @if ($appData->active_nic == 1)
                     {{ $appData->nic }}
                    @elseif ($appData->active_nic == 2)
                   {{ $appData->new_nic }}
                    @endif<br>
                    {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($appData->date_of_birth)->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($vacancy->date_closed))->format('%y Years, %m Months and %d Days'); }}<br>
                    {{ date("d-F-Y", strtotime($appData->date_of_birth)) }}
                </p>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                <p style="padding-left: 10px;font-size: 13px;">
                    <b><u>Higher Education</u></b><br>

                </p>
                <ul style="list-style-type: square;display:block">
                    @if($firstDegrees->count() > 0)
                    @foreach ($firstDegrees as $value)
                    <li >{{ $value->degree_titel }} - {{ $value->degree_university }} - {{ $value->degreeClassName->category_name }} - {{ date("d-M-Y", strtotime($value->eff_date)) }} - ({{ date("Y-F", strtotime($value->degree_start)) }} to {{ date("Y-F", strtotime($value->degree_end)) }})</li>
                    @endforeach
                    @endif
                    @if($postDegrees->count() > 0)
                    @foreach ($postDegrees as $value)
                    <li >{{ $value->degree_titel }} - {{ $value->degree_university }} - {{ $value->degreeClassName->category_name }} - {{ date("d-M-Y", strtotime($value->eff_date)) }} - ({{ date("Y-F", strtotime($value->degree_start)) }} to {{ date("Y-F", strtotime($value->degree_end)) }})</li>
                    @endforeach
                    @endif
                </ul>
                <p style="padding-left: 10px;font-size: 13px;">
                <b><u>Subject Offered for The First Degree</u></b><br>
                </p>
                <ul style="list-style-type: square;display:block">
                    @foreach ($degreeSubjects as $index => $item)
                    <li>{{ $item->degree_main_subject }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
                <p style="padding-left: 10px;font-size: 13px;">
                    <b><u>Other Qualification</u></b><br>
                </p>
                <p style="padding-left: 10px">
                    <b><u>Special Qualification</u></b><br>
                </p>
                <ul style="list-style-type: square;display:block">
                    @if($specialQulificationList->count() > 0)
                    @foreach ($specialQulificationList as $value)
                    <li><b>{{ $value->specialQulificationTypeName->category_name }} </b>- {{ $value->qulification_summary }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                    @endif
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                <p style="padding-left: 10px;font-size: 13px;">
                    <b><u>Professional Qualification</u></b><br>
                </p>
                <ul style="list-style-type: square;display:block">
                    @if($professionalQulificationList->count() > 0)
                     @foreach ($professionalQulificationList as $value)
                    <li>{{ $value->name }} - {{ $value->university }} - ({{ $value->start_year }} to {{ $value->end_year }})</li>
                    @endforeach
                    @endif
                </ul>
                <p style="padding-left: 10px;font-size: 13px;">
                    <b><u>Memberships/Fellowships</u></b><br>
                </p>
                <ul style="list-style-type: square;display:block">
                    @if($memberships->count() > 0)
                      @foreach ($memberships as $value)
                    <li>{{ $value->membershipTypeName->category_name }} - {{ $value->membership_university }} - ({{ $value->membership_start_year }} @if($value->membership_end_year != '') to {{ $value->membership_end_year }}@endif) - {{ $value->membershipCurrentStatusName->category_name }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                    @endif
                </ul>
                <p style="padding-left: 10px;font-size: 13px;">
                    <b><u>Research & Publication</u></b><br><br>
                    Annexure I
                </p>
            </td>


            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                <p style="padding-left: 10px;font-size: 13px;">
                    <b><u>Employment Records</u></b><br>
                </p>
                <ul style="list-style-type: square;display:block">
                    @if($employmentRecords->count() > 0)
                    @foreach ($employmentRecords as $value)
                    <li>{{ $value->designation }} - {{ $value->institution }} - ({{ date("d-M-Y", strtotime($value->start_date)) }} to {{ $value->end_date != '1970-01-01'  ?  date("d-M-Y", strtotime($value->end_date)) : 'Present' }}) </li>
                    @endforeach
                    @endif
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

what is the best way to solve the problem?